# nginx - перенаправление по URL сегменту

Tags: nginx, сеть, docker, веб-сервер

не могу понять как настроить nginx для перенаправления по URL сегменту.
Есть докер в котором nginx и десяток микросервисов.
Я хочу чтобы к микросервисам можно было обращатся не через порт, а по URL сегменту.
К примеру чтобы обратится к микросервису 1 нужно перейти по следующему URL http://localhost:7795/app1/ , а nginx перенаправит 172.20.1.1:8081.

```
localhost:7795/app1/ -> 172.20.1.2:8081
localhost:7795/app2/ -> 172.20.1.2:8082
localhost:7795/app3/ -> 172.20.1.3:8083
```

Вот пример конфигурации которую сделал я

```
http {
      server {
        server_name 172.20.1.1:8081;
        location /app1 {
           rewrite /app1/(.*) /$1 break;
           proxy_pass         http://172.20.1.1:8081;
           proxy_redirect     off;
           proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        }
      }
    }
```

Но меня перенаправляет на http://172.20.1.1:8081/app1

Не могли бы вы подсказать что я делаю не так?

Comment: Я убрал /app1 и $1 из rewrite. Теперь когда я перехожу в браузере по URL  http://localhost/app1 то меня перенаправляет на http://localhost/login?next=%2F. Это внутренние пути микросервиса, но по идее меня должно перенапрвлять на http://localhost/app1/login?next=%2F

Comment: Не правильно прочитал задание. Сообщение выше удалил. Включите `debug` логирование. Ну и проверять нужно например в `curl`, т.к. в браузере запросто может оказаться кэш перенаправлений.